# How to enable a logon server (Windows Server 2008 R2) for logon requests?

Tags: authentication, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I just started a new job where the previous Network Administrator left approx. 3 months ago and left me with extremely minimal information.  I have an account within the domain with administrator rights as well as several of the servers local administrator accounts/passwords.

Today there was not going to be anyone in the office, so I decided to do a test and do a power cycle on the servers.  Prior to executing this, I created VMWare Snapshots of the virtualized servers.

Upon rebooting I found that I could not login to any accounts; it was saying that "There are currently no logon Servers are available to service the logon request"

I quickly restored the virtual machines to their state prior to the power cycle, but I am still unable to login. I get the same error.  When I login to a local account, I can ping the Domain Controller and when I check the Domain Controller the Active Directory services appear to be running.

**Note:** Users that were logged in prior to the powercycle do not seem to be effected.
**Example:** My laptop was logged in and I have full access to all the network resources.

Answer (score 0):

There could be various reasons for that and it's difficult to give any precise advice as you didn't specify how many servers you have and how various roles are placed... But it could be something to do with servers reboot order, i.e. you should have your core services started first (AD DS, DNS, DHCP) then start other servers which depend on them. If you did it other way round it could be the reason of your issues.

And additionally DC restore from snapshot is not supported (not sure about VMWare, but for Hyper-V it's supported only if you run latest version of it and you should additionally have support from the guest OS for that, and with some caveats even then).

It shouldn't be very severe if you are restoring from relatively "fresh" snapshot, but just keep in mind that Kerberos and AD DS require time to be in sync across domain and big hops of time on DC can impact your environment negatively.

Error message on a clients point either or inability of machine to locate DC or machine account unable to authenticate against DC. Apart from other things you may try & re-join this machine to the domain.